# Docker ubuntu image download test failed

Tags: 14.04, docker

I am trying to install use docker as one of my applications depends on it. I followed the installation instructions for the latest docker from [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) for Ubuntu 14.04. After the installation, I performed the test as mentioned in the website

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
        Pulling repository ubuntu
        FATA[0035] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images:          dial tcp 162.242.195.84:443: connection refused
```

Does this mean the docker is not functioning properly? Can you please tell me how I can fix this, if that's the case?

Comment: are you able to ping "index.docker.io"?

Comment: yes am able to @vembutech

Comment: are you able to open https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images in your web browser?

Comment: I opened @Fabby and I got a whole page of characters and probably commands. Is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: Yup, normal. **Seems you hit a bug.  Contact the Docker team.**

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables in `/etc/default/docker` (setting your proxy IP and port). The example below is looking for local cntlm doing proxy authentication:

```
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
export https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
```